# is there a pure C# ZeroConf , bonjour, or dns-sd available?

Tags: c#, .net, zeroconf, .net-micro-framework, dns-sd

I'm building a .net-microframework app that uses Zeroconf.  The existing zeroconf solutions all seem to either rely on dns-sd.dll or some other interop function of .net which is not supported in .netmf.

Is there a pure C# version of zeroconf (or dns-sd) out there that you know of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bringing Closure to this tumbleweed:

[ZeroConf](http://zeroconf.codeplex.com/) on codeplex is a very comprehensive project.  Though I'm not sure if it's fully tested.

(personally I was hoping for a smaller and simpler implementation ;)

Comment: Be careful with that zeroconf from codeplex. Its under the MS-RL not the MS-PL. That is a viral license that says your source has to also be open.

Comment: This is pretty old, but I asked about the license on that project and it was a mistake that it was MS-RL.  The license has since been changed to MS-PL.  http://zeroconf.codeplex.com/license